# Run script from sublime-text

Tags: 16.04, scripts, sublime-text

I have a script that writes public keys on servers that I use. In previous versions of Ubuntu 16.04 I could use it normally. I do not know if it is related to Sublime Text or Ubuntu itself. But today I can not anymore. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Caso não tenha a chave , use o comando: 'ssh-keygen -t rsa' para gerar a mesma. 

chave="/home/douglas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
usuario="admin"
host="192.168.1.2"
porta="22"

ssh-copy-id -i $chave -p $porta $usuario"@"$host
```

When I execute it, I get the following error in the Sublime Text console:

```
> usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed:
> "/home/douglas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting
> to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already
> installed /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed
> -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory Permission
> denied, please try again. ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No
> such file or directory Permission denied, please try again.
> ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
> Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Run via terminal, the script works. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83986/tell-ssh-to-use-a-graphical-prompt-for-key-passphrase